# Moving a product from development to production

Tags: plone

I set up a development environment and developed a product: it's listed under "develop" in buildout. How can I get the same product running in production? None of the tutorials seem to take it this far, from what I have found. How do I go about making it a fully fledged egg? Or should I run develop.cfg on the production server (I'd think not).

Comment: Kindly mention the technologies you are using. I may be able to suggest something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue to deploy the product in 'development' mode; it is just a local egg that'll satisfy *all* version requirements.

You could publish the egg to an (internal) index server, and use it as a proper buildout dependency, but that is not required. It all depends on your deployment strategy.

For recent projects, we just stuck to the first option; the source of the site is part of the buildout repository, and new deployments are tagged with a version number. The egg remains listed under the `develop` line in buildout. The extra hassle of creating a production egg just isn't worth it, not when that same egg is never used outside of the site-specific buildout.

Comment: is this assertion error because I haven't run the develop.cfg buildout: http://pastie.org/8635531#2 ?

Comment: No, you have a permission problem; the current user cannot write in the `/home/Plone-4.3.2/zinstance/src/hccrems.types/hccrems.types.egg-info` directory.

Comment: @Adripants: feesh has encountered the [same error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174270/using-linguaplone-in-plone-4-the-tinymce-editor-is-not-showing-up#comment37517525_24174270), if you could resolve and want to share, it'll be great, if you tell us about it on [#13332](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13332), Best regards, ida

Comment: Looks like a different issue to me, or could the link be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I shared your pain for ages. I never did bother to create eggs until I came across Dylan Jay's collective.hostout. It eggifies my development packages and deploys them to as many hosts as I need.