# Using LinguaPlone in Plone 4, the TinyMCE editor is not showing up

Tags: plone, linguaplone

I'm using LinguaPlone 4.1.3 with an instance of Plone 4.3 and upon hitting "Translate into..." and choosing one of the languages, on the following editing screen the TinyMCE editor does not show up.

[image: Missing editor on the right column under Body Text]

I'm able to switch to Plone output HTML in the dropdown menu there on the right, and it gives me just the HTML box. However, none of the options display the TinyMCE editor. When editing normal pages (i.e. not translated content), TinyMCE works fine — it's set as the default for the site, and also the default in my personal preferences.

[image: HTML editor shows up sometimes]

Any ideas to fix this or what to look for would be great! On another site on this same Plone instance, the translation functionality works fine (TinyMCE shows up as it should).

Also, in case it helps, here's the output HTML for the area where the editor would be. Thanks!

```
<div data-fieldname="text" data-uid="c61b5fcb98874fe3a3cf16538bcf88e3" id="archetypes-fieldname-text" class="field ArchetypesRichWidget ">
          <span></span>


            <label for="text" class="formQuestion">
                Body Text

                <span id="text_help" class="formHelp"></span>
            </label>


          <div class="fieldErrorBox"></div>





<div class="fieldTextFormat">
    <label>Text Format</label>

    <select name="text_text_format" id="text_text_format" tabindex="-1">
      <option value="text/html" selected="selected">HTML</option>
      <option value="text/x-web-textile">Textile</option>
      <option value="text/x-plone-outputfilters-html">Plone Output Filters HTML</option>
    </select>
</div>








        <div>

   <div>

  <textarea data-mce-config="{&quot;link_shortcuts_html&quot;: [&quot;\n        &lt;img src=\&quot;img/home.png\&quot; /&gt;\n        &lt;a id=\&quot;home\&quot; href=\&quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple\&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;\n        &quot;, &quot;\n        &lt;img src=\&quot;img/folder_current.png\&quot; /&gt;\n        &lt;a id=\&quot;currentfolder\&quot; href=\&quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/improving-information-use/improving-information-use-zh\&quot;&gt;Current Folder&lt;/a&gt;\n        &quot;], &quot;theme&quot;: &quot;advanced&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_path_location&quot;: &quot;bottom&quot;, &quot;entity_encoding&quot;: &quot;raw&quot;, &quot;plugins&quot;: &quot;advhr,definitionlist,directionality,emotions,fullscreen,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,media,nonbreaking,noneditable,pagebreak,paste,plonebrowser,ploneinlinestyles,plonestyle,preview,print,save,searchreplace,tabfocus,table,visualchars,xhtmlxtras,contextmenu&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_path&quot;: false, &quot;allow_captioned_images&quot;: true, &quot;atd_rpc_id&quot;: &quot;Products.TinyMCE-admin&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_source_editor_height&quot;: 400, &quot;directionality&quot;: &quot;ltr&quot;, &quot;table_styles&quot;: &quot;Fancy listing=listing;Invisible grid=invisible&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_resizing&quot;: true, &quot;theme_advanced_buttons2&quot;: &quot;link,unlink,anchor,tablecontrols,code,fullscreen&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_buttons3&quot;: &quot;&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_buttons1&quot;: &quot;style,bold,italic,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,numlist,definitionlist,outdent,indent,image&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_buttons4&quot;: &quot;&quot;, &quot;buttons&quot;: [&quot;style&quot;, &quot;bold&quot;, &quot;italic&quot;, &quot;justifyleft&quot;, &quot;justifycenter&quot;, &quot;justifyright&quot;, &quot;justifyfull&quot;, &quot;bullist&quot;, &quot;numlist&quot;, &quot;definitionlist&quot;, &quot;outdent&quot;, &quot;indent&quot;, &quot;image&quot;, &quot;link&quot;, &quot;unlink&quot;, &quot;anchor&quot;, &quot;tablecontrols&quot;, &quot;code&quot;, &quot;fullscreen&quot;], &quot;document_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/improving-information-use/improving-information-use-zh&quot;, &quot;autoresize&quot;: false, &quot;valid_inline_styles&quot;: &quot;text-align,list-style-type,float,padding-left&quot;, &quot;toolbar_width&quot;: 440, &quot;language&quot;: &quot;zh&quot;, &quot;mode&quot;: &quot;exact&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_styles&quot;: &quot;[{ title: \&quot;Text\&quot;, tag: \&quot;\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Normal paragraph\&quot;, tag: \&quot;p\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Call-out\&quot;, tag: \&quot;p\&quot;, className: \&quot;callout\&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Clear floats\&quot;, tag: \&quot;div\&quot;, className: \&quot;visualClear\&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Heading\&quot;, tag: \&quot;h2\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Literal\&quot;, tag: \&quot;pre\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Pull-quote\&quot;, tag: \&quot;blockquote\&quot;, className: \&quot;pullquote\&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Subheading\&quot;, tag: \&quot;h3\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Text\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Selection\&quot;, tag: \&quot;\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Selection\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;(remove style)\&quot;, tag: \&quot;\&quot;, className: \&quot;\&quot;, type: \&quot;Selection\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Discreet\&quot;, tag: \&quot;span\&quot;, className: \&quot;discreet\&quot;, type: \&quot;Selection\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Highlight\&quot;, tag: \&quot;span\&quot;, className: \&quot;visualHighlight\&quot;, type: \&quot;Selection\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Tables\&quot;, tag: \&quot;table\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Plain cell\&quot;, tag: \&quot;td\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Fancy listing\&quot;, tag: \&quot;table\&quot;, className: \&quot;listing\&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Invisible grid\&quot;, tag: \&quot;table\&quot;, className: \&quot;invisible\&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Even row\&quot;, tag: \&quot;tr\&quot;, className: \&quot;even\&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Heading cell\&quot;, tag: \&quot;th\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Odd row\&quot;, tag: \&quot;tr\&quot;, className: \&quot;odd\&quot;, type: \&quot;Tables\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lists\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ul\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lists\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lists\&quot;, tag: \&quot;dl\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lists\&quot;, tag: \&quot;dl\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Circle\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ul\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeCircle\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Definition description\&quot;, tag: \&quot;dd\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Definition term\&quot;, tag: \&quot;dt\&quot;, className: \&quot; \&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Disc\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ul\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeDisc\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lower Alpha\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeLowerAlpha\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Lower Roman\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeLowerRoman\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Numbers\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeDecimal\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Square\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ul\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeSquare\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Upper Alpha\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeUpperAlpha\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Upper Roman\&quot;, tag: \&quot;ol\&quot;, className: \&quot;listTypeUpperRoman\&quot;, type: \&quot;Lists\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Print\&quot;, tag: \&quot;\&quot;, className: \&quot;-\&quot;, type: \&quot;Print\&quot; },{ title: \&quot;Page break (print only)\&quot;, tag: \&quot;div\&quot;, className: \&quot;pageBreak\&quot;, type: \&quot;Print\&quot; }]&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_toolbar_align&quot;: &quot;left&quot;, &quot;media_strict&quot;: false, &quot;body_id&quot;: &quot;content&quot;, &quot;labels&quot;: {&quot;label_style_ldots&quot;: &quot;Style...&quot;, &quot;label_addnewimage&quot;: &quot;Add new Image&quot;, &quot;label_browseimage&quot;: &quot;Image Browser&quot;, &quot;label_paragraph&quot;: &quot;Normal paragraph&quot;, &quot;label_print&quot;: &quot;Print&quot;, &quot;label_search_results&quot;: &quot;Search results:&quot;, &quot;label_internal_path&quot;: &quot;you_are_here&quot;, &quot;label_no_items&quot;: &quot;No items in this folder&quot;, &quot;label_browser&quot;: &quot;Browser&quot;, &quot;label_shortcuts&quot;: &quot;Shortcuts&quot;, &quot;label_addnewfile&quot;: &quot;Add new File&quot;, &quot;label_styles&quot;: &quot;(remove style)&quot;, &quot;label_tables&quot;: &quot;Tables&quot;, &quot;label_selection&quot;: &quot;Selection&quot;, &quot;label_browselink&quot;: &quot;Link Browser&quot;, &quot;label_text&quot;: &quot;Text&quot;, &quot;label_lists&quot;: &quot;Lists&quot;, &quot;label_no_anchors&quot;: &quot;No anchors in this page&quot;, &quot;label_plain_cell&quot;: &quot;Plain cell&quot;}, &quot;rooted&quot;: false, &quot;navigation_root_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_source_editor_width&quot;: 600, &quot;document_base_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/improving-information-use/&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_resizing_use_cookie&quot;: true, &quot;fix_list_elements&quot;: false, &quot;inlinepopups_skin&quot;: &quot;plonepopup&quot;, &quot;portal_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple&quot;, &quot;valid_elements&quot;: &quot;i[class|dir|id|style|title],article[class|dir|id|style|title],a[accesskey|charset|class|coords|dir|href|hreflang|id|name|rel|rev|shape|style|tabindex|target|title|type],object[align|archive|class|classid|codebase|codetype|data|declare|dir|height|hspace|id|name|standby|style|tabindex|title|type|usemap|vspace|width],q[cite|class|dir|id|style|title],u[class|dir|id|style|title],bdo[class|dir|id|style|title],hgroup[class|dir|id|style|title],acronym[class|dir|id|style|title],ul[class|compact|dir|id|style|title|type],var[class|dir|id|style|title],sup[class|dir|id|style|title],colgroup[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|span|style|title|width],embed[*],col[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|span|style|title|width],sub[class|dir|id|style|title],nav[class|dir|id|style|title],strong[class|dir|id|style|title],map[class|dir|id|name|title],datalist[class|dir|id|style|title],address[class|dir|id|style|title],tfoot[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|style|title],dd[class|dir|id|style|title],ruby[class|dir|id|style|title],dl[class|compact|dir|id|style|title],video[class|dir|id|style|title],#p[align|class|dir|id|style|title],dt[class|dir|id|style|title],footer[class|dir|id|style|title],body[alink|background|class|dir|id|link|style|text|title|vlink],meter[class|dir|id|style|title],area[accesskey|alt|class|coords|dir|href|id|nohref|shape|style|tabindex|target|title],dialog[class|dir|id|style|title],html[dir|id|xmlns],small[class|dir|id|style|title],cite[class|dir|id|style|title],details[class|dir|id|style|title],header[class|dir|id|style|title],aside[class|dir|id|style|title],del[cite|class|datetime|dir|id|style|title],keygen[class|dir|id|style|title],figure[class|dir|id|style|title],audio[class|dir|id|style|title],abbr[class|dir|id|style|title],canvas[class|dir|id|style|title],mark[class|dir|id|style|title],br[class|clear|id|style|title],div[align|class|dir|id|style|title],table[align|class|dir|id|style|summary|title],command[class|dir|id|style|title],caption[align|class|dir|id|style|title],source[class|dir|id|style|title],samp[class|dir|id|style|title],rt[class|dir|id|style|title],tt[class|dir|id|style|title],thead[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|style|title],tr[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|style|title],meta[content|dir|http-equiv|id|name|scheme],tbody[align|char|charoff|class|dir|id|style|title],td[abbr|align|axis|char|charoff|class|colspan|dir|headers|id|nowrap|rowspan|scope|style|title],output[class|dir|id|style|title],ol[class|compact|dir|id|style|title|type],th[abbr|align|axis|char|charoff|class|colspan|dir|headers|id|nowrap|rowspan|scope|style|title],blockquote[cite|class|dir|id|style|title],b[class|dir|id|style|title],span[class|dir|id|style|title],title[dir|id],time[class|dir|id|style|title],iframe[align|class|dir|frameborder|height|id|longdesc|marginheight|marginwidth|name|scrolling|src|style|title|width],dfn[class|dir|id|style|title],img[align|alt|class|dir|height|hspace|id|ismap&lt;ismap|longdesc|name|src|style|title|usemap|vspace|width],ins[cite|class|datetime|dir|id|style|title],hr[align|class|dir|id|noshade|size|style|title|width],progress[class|dir|id|style|title],h6[align|class|dir|id|style|title],em[class|dir|id|style|title],base[href|id|target],script[charset|defer|id|language|src|type],pre[class|dir|id|style|title|width],kbd[class|dir|id|style|title],section[class|dir|id|style|title],rp[class|dir|id|style|title],li[class|dir|id|style|title|type],head[dir|id|profile],code[class|dir|id|style|title],h3[align|class|dir|id|style|title],h2[align|class|dir|id|style|title],h1[align|class|dir|id|style|title],param[id|name|type|value|valuetype],h5[align|class|dir|id|style|title],h4[align|class|dir|id|style|title],big[class|dir|id|style|title]&quot;, &quot;content_css&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/portal_tinymce/@@tinymce-getstyle&quot;, &quot;theme_advanced_resize_horizontal&quot;: false, &quot;link_using_uids&quot;: true, &quot;atd_ignore_strings&quot;: &quot;Zope,Plone,TinyMCE&quot;, &quot;contextmenu&quot;: true, &quot;livesearch&quot;: true, &quot;body_class&quot;: &quot;documentContent&quot;, &quot;thumbnail_size&quot;: [&quot;tile&quot;, 64, 64], &quot;skin&quot;: &quot;plone&quot;, &quot;anchor_selector&quot;: &quot;h2,h3&quot;, &quot;atd_show_types&quot;: &quot;Bias Language,Cliches,Complex Expression,Diacritical Marks,Double Negatives,Hidden Verbs,Jargon Language,Passive voice,Phrases to Avoid,Redundant Expression&quot;, &quot;atd_rpc_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/@@&quot;, &quot;script_url&quot;: &quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/tiny_mce_gzip.js&quot;, &quot;customplugins&quot;: [&quot;plonebrowser&quot;], &quot;num_of_thumb_columns&quot;: 4, &quot;table_firstline_th&quot;: true, &quot;image_shortcuts_html&quot;: [&quot;\n        &lt;img src=\&quot;img/home.png\&quot; /&gt;\n        &lt;a id=\&quot;home\&quot; href=\&quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple\&quot;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;\n        &quot;, &quot;\n        &lt;img src=\&quot;img/folder_current.png\&quot; /&gt;\n        &lt;a id=\&quot;currentfolder\&quot; href=\&quot;http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/improving-information-use/improving-information-use-zh\&quot;&gt;Current Folder&lt;/a&gt;\n        &quot;], &quot;theme_advanced_toolbar_location&quot;: &quot;top&quot;, &quot;gecko_spellcheck&quot;: true}" data-pattern="plone-tinymce" class="mce_editable" id="text" name="text" rows="25" cols="40" style="visibility: hidden;"></textarea>

  <div style="margin-top: -1em; display: none;" class="discreet suppressVisualEditor">
    <a href="http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/improving-information-use/improving-information-use-zh/translate_item?tinymce.suppress=text&amp;">
      Edit without visual editor
    </a>
  </div>




</div>

</div>



          <div class="fieldUploadFile">
              <span class="discreet">or upload a file (existing content will be replaced)</span>
              <input type="file" name="text_file" id="text_file" size="30" originalvalue="">
          </div>

        </div>
```

The JS debug console says:

```
Failed to load: http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/langs/zh.js
```

[image: Debug console]

Comment: Do you get any JS errors? Enable debug console in your browser an refresh the site.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks, good call. Adding the results on the original question, it says — Failed to load: http://169.237.124.123:8082/ChinaApple/langs/zh.js

Comment: Is that missing from LinguaPlone or is there a way I can reinstall that .js file?

Comment: In Products.TinyMCE with version 1.3 the 'zh'-locale has been removed and instead 'zh_CN' and 'zh_TW' were added, see [#12126](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12126). Using an older version would work for now. Please file a report/add a comment to the existing ticket.

Comment: Or a better workaround for now: Make a copy of P.TinyMCE-1.3.6, add it as a dev-egg to buildout and copy 'locales/zh' and 'skins/tinymce/langs/zh.js' of version 1.2.17 into the the dev-egg.

Comment: P.S.: "Make a copy" = clone of GitHub

Comment: @IdaEbkes Well that's it, I assumed something like that.

Comment: @Mathias: Thanks for confirming. And for encouraging feesh to use a debug-tool, so more details have been revealed :)

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll give this a shot on Monday and will report back on the results!

Comment: Hey @IdaEbkes! Sorry, this is going to sound stupid. I have all the files set up as you suggested in /develop-eggs/Products.TinyMCE-1.3.6 — what changes do I need to make in buildout.cfg to make it recognize the new version? Do I just change the version number in versions.cfg to 1.3.6?

Comment: Assuming you were using the UnifiedInstaller, put the product in the "src"-directory. Then in buildout.cfg add `src/Products.TInyMCE` after the line `develop = `, and after `eggs = ` add product-name, too (without "src/"). LBNL: Run builodut, run, restart instance.

Comment: Hmm so I get a permission error when running buildout, it looks like this: http://pastie.org/9301374 — is it trying to overwrite the existing TinyMCE? Do I need to chown something first or something? I'm running buildout as sudo -u plone_buildout if that helps. Thanks Ida!

Comment: I admittedly don't sudo (in order to avoid permisson-mess-ups during dev) and neither dived into finding out all of the possible implications, maybe [this quest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21761403/override-sanity-check-when-running-plone-buildout) is giving more enlightments. But for a wild guess, try `sudo bin/buildout`, suspecting that can help, in case someone executed this before.

Comment: Can you execute buildout at all, if you remove the P.TinyMCE-entries? Maybe this is worth a new quest, probably a bug in zc.buildout, even. Concerning the orig-quest: If you could leave a note about the conflict in #12126, that'll be cool, in case other run into this, too, TIA.

Comment: Ok, about the assertion-error, looks like [#9148](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/9148) is describing exactly your issue, please continue troubleshooting there.

Comment: Sorry it's not #9148, but [#13332](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13332).

Comment: Good call, just added the comment to #12126! I am able to run buildout without the TinyMCE entries although there's an interesting bit in the middle where it runs setpermissions and stuff: http://pastie.org/9302452

Comment: Hi @IdaEbkes! So I sat down with @eleddy today and I'm not sure what she did but she got everything working. I'll see if she can put an answer down here. The buildout issue though was that the permission on the src/Product.TinyMCE files were wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eleddy solved it!! Here's her response:

Yo yo yoes! For those who don't know, Chinese (China) is a combined language so you have to go into the portal_language tool in the ZMI and check the box that says "Allow combined languages", then the other Chinese will show up. Two bottles of celebration beer later and you are Chinesing all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Chinese(zh_CN) is usually called for short Chinese(zh)

In view @@language-controlpanel 
Available languages (The languages in which the site should be translatable.) 
Selected 'Chinese (China)' rather than 'Chinese'.

Comment: Oh man, I would love if this just worked!! Unfortunately, only "Chinese" shows up as an option for me: http://cl.ly/image/0N3n0J0j2c0K